# Error in decoding attachment in MIME using perl

Tags: perl, mime

I wrote a script in perl to make multipart MIME message attaching an image here is the script

```
use MIME::Parser;
use FileHandle;

$ffh = FileHandle->new;
if ( $ffh->open(">m2.txt") ) {

    #print <$fh>;
}

### Create an entity:
$top = MIME::Entity->build(
    From    => 'me@myhost.com',
    To      => 'you@yourhost.com',
    Subject => "Hello, nurse!",
    Data    => "How are you today"
);

### Attach stuff to it:
$top->attach(
    Path     => "im.jpg",
    Type     => "image/jpg",
    Encoding => "base64"
);

### Output it:
$top->print($ffh);
```

after that I tried to parse the generated output message from the above script using the following code

```
use MIME::Parser;
use FileHandle;

$fh = FileHandle->new;
if ( $fh->open("<m2.txt") ) {

    #print <$fh>;
}

### Create parser, and set some parsing options:
my $parser = new MIME::Parser;
$parser->output_to_core(1);

### Parse input:
$entity = $parser->parse($fh) or die "parse failed\n";

print $entity->head->get('subject');
print $entity->head->get('from');

print $entity->head->get('to');
print $entity->head->get('cc');
print $entity->head->get('date');
print $entity->head->get('content-type');

my $parts = $entity->parts(1);
my $body  = $parts->bodyhandle;
print $parts->head->get('content-type');

$ffh = FileHandle->new;
if ( $ffh->open(">C:/Users/Aamer/Desktop/im.jpg") ) {
    $body->print($ffh);
}
```

now every thing parse correctly and returned the values right except for the output image as attachment the image some how is corrupted I tried to hex compare them there were some difference between extracted image and the original image can any one tell me what's wrong here ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pathname indicates you're on Windows, where Perl opens files in text mode by default.  That means when writing a file it converts every occurrence of 0x0A (LF) in your image to 0x0D 0x0A (CRLF), corrupting your image.

Open the file in binary mode:

```
$ffh->open("C:/Users/Aamer/Desktop/im.jpg", "wb")
```

Comment: thank you very much, the problem is exactly like you said , although "wb" didn't work for me on windows. binmode($ffh) did work for me instead. just sharing this for future help , but really thanks

Comment: `"wb"` should work.  Did you remove the `>` from the front of your filename when you added the `"wb"`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you closing the filehandle before attaching the file? Might be a buffering issue. Closing the filehandle will flush the data to the file.